# Getting a null pointer exception when mocking and spying in a test class

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

```
Android Studio 3.5.3
Kotlin 1.3
```

I am trying to test some simple code but I keep getting the following exception:

```
IllegalStateException: gsonWrapper.fromJson<Map…ring, String>>() {}.type) must not be null
```

I am using the spy and mocking the return so it will return a null. As I want to test the error path.

Not sure if I am doing something wrong with my stubbing or not. But can't seem to resolve this exception.

Using a wrapper class to wrap the gson implementation and spying on this in the test

```
public class GsonWrapper implements IGsonWrapper {

    private Gson gson;

    public GsonWrapper(Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    @Override public <T> T fromJson(String json, Type typeOf) {
        return gson.fromJson(json, typeOf);
    }
}
```

Implementation of my class that is under test

```
class MoviePresenterImp(
        private val gsonWrapper: IGsonWrapper) : MoviePresenter {

    private companion object {
        const val movieKey = "movieKey"
    }

    override fun saveMovieState(movieJson: String) {
            val movieMap = serializeStringToMap(movieJson)

            when (movieMap.getOrElse(movieKey, {""})) {
                /* do something here */
            }
    }

    // Exception return from this method
    private fun serializeStringToMap(ccpaStatus: String): Map<String, String> =
            gsonWrapper.fromJson<Map<String, String>>(ccpaStatus, object : TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.type) // Exception
}
```

The actual test class, just keeping everything simple

```
class MoviePresenterImpTest {
    private lateinit var moviePresenterImp: MoviePresenterImp
    private val gsonWrapper: GsonWrapper = GsonWrapper(Gson())
    private val spyGsonWrapper = spy(gsonWrapper)

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        moviePresenterImp = MoviePresenterImp(spyGsonWrapper)
    }

    @Test
    fun `should not save any movie when there is an error`() {
        // Arrange
        val mapType: Type = object : TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.type
        whenever(spyGsonWrapper.fromJson<Map<String, String>>("{\"movie\":\"movieId\"}", mapType)).thenReturn(null)

        // Act
        moviePresenterImp.saveMovieState("{\"movie\":\"movieId\"}")

        // Assert here
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. Do you want to allow `MoviePresenterImp.serializeStringToMap` to return `null`? At the moment it is not possible and that's what you are testing in your unit test:

- what will happen when `gsonWrapper.fromJson` returns `null`?
- `serializeStringToMap` will throw an exception because its return type is declared to be non-nullable (Kotlin adds a null-check under the hood).

In fact,`spyGsonWrapper.fromJson` only returns `null` if `gson.fromJson` returns `null`. According to the Gson's java docs, it may happen only if the `json` argument is `null` (if `json` is invalid the method throws `JsonSyntaxException`). So you should either:

- check if the `json` parameter is `null` in the `spyGsonWrapper.fromJson` and throw IllegalArgumentException if it is. This will ensure that the method never returns `null` (btw. you could add a `@NotNull` annotation, see [nullability-annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations)). You can keep `serializeStringToMap` as it is but you need to change the test, because it makes no sense anymore.
- if you prefer returning `null` instead of throwing an exception, you need to change the MoviePresenterImp.serializeStringToMap as suggested by @duongdt3

Here is an example test:

```
class MoviePresenterImpTest {

    private lateinit var moviePresenter: MoviePresenterImp
    private lateinit var spyGsonWrapper: GsonWrapper

    @Rule @JvmField
    var thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        spyGsonWrapper = Mockito.mock(GsonWrapper::class.java)
        moviePresenter = MoviePresenterImp(spyGsonWrapper)
    }

    @Test
    fun `should not save any movie when GsonWrapper throws an error`() {
        // Given
        Mockito.`when`(spyGsonWrapper.fromJson<Map<String, String>>(anyString(), any(Type::class.java)))
            .thenThrow(JsonSyntaxException("test"))
        // Expect
        thrown.expect(JsonSyntaxException::class.java)
        // When
        moviePresenter.saveMovieState("{\"movie\":\"movieId\"}")
    }

   // Or without mocking at all

    @Test
    fun `should not save any movie when Gson throws error`() {
        // Given
        moviePresenter = MoviePresenterImp(GsonWrapper(Gson()))
        // Expect
        thrown.expect(JsonSyntaxException::class.java)
        // When
        moviePresenter.saveMovieState("Some invalid json")
    }

    // If you want to perform additional checks after an exception was thrown
    // then you need a try-catch block

    @Test
    fun `should not save any movie when Gson throws error and `() {
        // Given
        moviePresenter = MoviePresenterImp(GsonWrapper(Gson()))
        // When
        try {
            moviePresenter.saveMovieState("Some invalid json")
            Assert.fail("Expected JsonSyntaxException")
        } catch(ex : JsonSyntaxException) {}
        // Additional checks
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I found problems here:

You must use nullable Map? instead of non-null Map in MoviePresenterImp (Kotlin code), because in Unit Test class, you spy gsonWrapper, and force method 'spyGsonWrapper.fromJson' return null.

***It OK now.***

```
fun saveMovieState(movieJson: String) {
        val movieMap = serializeStringToMap(movieJson)

        when (movieMap?.getOrElse(movieKey, { "" })) {
            /* do something here */
        }
    }

    // Exception return from this method
    private fun serializeStringToMap(ccpaStatus: String): Map<String, String>? {
        val type: Type =
            object : TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.type
        return gsonWrapper.fromJson(ccpaStatus, type) // Exception
    }
```

Comment: Hi, yes that worked. However, I don't want to return a null map and I would like to keep it as a `non-null`. I think what I am trying to achieve is to return a map that has null contents. So when `movieMap.getOrElse()` will return a null. That is what I was trying to mock. Having the movieMap contain a null is something I am not sure how to do?.

Comment: Actually, about parse JSON with Gson, you should support for null case, sometimes JSON text doesn't match with our expectation. You have a test case for null is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

With your setup you're looking for `emptyMap()` instead of `null`

```
whenever(spyGsonWrapper.fromJson<Map<String, String>>("{\"movie\":\"movieId\"}", mapType))
    .thenReturn(emptyMap())
```

This will comply with the signature, as it's non-null

```
fun serializeStringToMap(ccpaStatus: String): Map<String, String>
```

Also it'll enter the else-block within the `movieMap.getOrElse()` call.